# Let $v$ and $w$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $|v|=4$, $|w|=3$, and $v \cdot w=8$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

(a) If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, express the length of $av+bw$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

(b) What is the length of $v \times w$?

I know that I would have to work backwards to find the actual vectors, $v$ and $w$, but I don't know how I would do that.

Comment: Hint: you can't find the "actual vectors" but you have enough information to find the angle between them.

Comment: For the first part of the question, you don't need to do anything apart from take the scalar product of the expression with itself, and you have enough information to eliminate $v$ and $w$. For the second part you can compute the cosine of the angle between the vectors and hence the sine (using a well known formula) without having to identify the angle.

Comment: I think I was able to solve part (b), but I am unsure what you mean by the scalar product of itself. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hint for (a): Let $u = av +bw$. Can you find $u\cdot u$?

Answer (score 1):

Relevant for (b): 
$$\mathbb{a}\bullet\mathbb{b}=|\mathbb{a}|\,|\mathbb{b}|\cos\theta;$$

$$|\mathbb{a}\times \mathbb{b}|=|\mathbb{a}|\,|\mathbb{b}|\sin\theta.$$

Also,

$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1.$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Do you have any idea how I can solve (a)?